# Are there any operating systems that utilize only user threads?

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling, threads, os-kernel, multi-tasking

We're going over threading models in my freshman CS class. Are there any examples of operating systems that use exclusively user threads (N:1)? It looks like 1:1 is far and away the most common model but I wanted to see live examples of this other model. Google had been inconsistent and it seems a lot disagree on which actually is user thread based or not. As best as I can tell it hasn't been used in years.

Any programs or languages that utilize user threads count too.

All help appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There might be some research OS's for embedded systems that use only user threads, but I'm not aware of any production systems right now.  The challenge is that you can't get security/isolation for multiple users with user threads (at least, not without a lot of extra work, like using software fault isolation and more).